# How to implement Dependency Injection on a headless IoT BackgroundTask?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, iot, headless, windows-10-iot-core

I just bought a Raspberry Pi, installing Windows 10 IoT on it, and I want to start playing with some GPIO stuff, but I'd like to write some clean code; for me, that means coding to interfaces and injecting dependencies... but that does not seem possible.

I tried `UnityContainer` and the `IServiceCollection`, but VS complains that neither are "valid WinRT types"... so... what is, and how to do this?